# How ios app data connect to azure sql database?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, azure-sql-database

I am new xcode and swift lanuage, I am making a ios application with xcode, it is a qr code genrator and I want to make qr code data sync to azure sql database, but I don't know how to write the function to sync data to azure sql database. How should I write the function to sync the result of qrcode generator to azure sql database?

Here is my qr code generator Code:

```
func Generate(id:string)-> UIImage {
        let com = id.data(using: .utf8)
        filter.setValue(com, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
```

how could i sync the result data to azure sql database? do any experts know how to write the function?

Comment: I’m sure the APIs documentation can give you a headstart. There is usually a Getting started section.

Comment: @loremipsum So I need something like web API to do make mobile application data sync to azure app services which configure with azure sql database, right?

Comment: Yes, you need an api from azure

Comment: so azure api management or i need to make my own api from visual studio?

Comment: Go to the azure website, explore their options

Answer (score 0):

To connect with IOS app first you need to create mobile app in azure portal.
for that you can follow below procedure:

Go to search bar in azure portal and search for app service click on that and create new by giving required details:

[image]

Click on create, after deployment go to configuration under settings and click on new application settings.  In the  **Add/Edit application setting**  page, enter  **Name**  as **MobileAppsManagement_EXTENSION_VERSION**  and Value as  **latest**  and hit OK.

for creating database connection Download the client SDK quickstarts for the following platforms:

[iOS (Objective-C)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/iOS)
[iOS (Swift)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/iOS-Swift)
[Android (Java)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/android)
[Xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/xamarin.iOS)
[Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/xamarin.android)
[Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/xamarin.forms)
[Cordova](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/cordova)
[Windows (C#)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/windows-uwp-cs)

Create Azure sql database and copy the connection string of database:

```
Server=tcp:<server>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<db>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=demouser;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

[image]

Add the connection string to your  **mobile app**  In App Service, you can manage connection strings for your application by using the  **Configuration**  option in the menu.

To add a connection string:

1. Click on the  **Application settings**  tab.
2. Click on  **[+] New connection string**.
3. You will need to provide  **Name**,  **Value**  and  **Type**  for your connection string.
4. Type  **Name**  as  `MS_TableConnectionString`
5. Value should be the connecting string you formed in the step before.
6. If you are adding a connection string to a SQL Azure database choose  **SQLAzure**  under  **type**.

In this way you can connect azure SQL database to IOS app.
for more clarification you can refere

1.[Create an iOS app - Azure Mobile Apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started)

2.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50195df-0fab-4361-82ac-e75a338b69cc/connect-to-azure-sql-database-from-ios-app-written-in-swift